# JSP page is not getting refreshed after updating

Tags: jsp

JSP page is not getting refreshed after updating. I tried deleting browser cache, but id didn't have any effect. Any suggestion is of great help. I am using Tomcat server and Eclipse Ganymede.

Comment: You have a second level cache lying around? Like EhCache or JBoss cache? Most of these have a file system based persistence. Will remain even between container restarts. Check expiry intervals if you have any.

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in your jsp page:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
//prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

It will not cache your page

Comment: This actually helped me refresh the "include" files!

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete the tomcat's work folder contents and then redeploy the application. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You checked the configuration of Tomcat?

There's a setting "reloading", which should be set to "true" to allow Tomcat to check for changes to JSP files.

See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration

EDIT: Of course, Eclipse may not be deploying your updated JSP file to the Tomcat folder?

Comment: IMO this is a better option!

Answer (score 0):

- Check Tomcat server properties in Eclipse whether Auto publishing is enabled.
- If the Auto publishing is not enabled clean the project properly.
- Even if the problem persists.

  Export **WAR** file of project and deploy it in server by not using Eclipse to check whether Eclipse is running fine.

Comment: Hi Srikanth, it is hosted in remote linux machine so I dod't know how to check properties there

Comment: Did you try to take WAR file and deploy it in remote linux machine?

Comment: we don't use WAR file , we build it using ant

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/MyEclipse/Netbeans - Just DELETE your old SERVER. And then again create NEW SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue too. I solved it by setting **firefox** as Web browser and set "Limit Cache to 0 mb."
Open firefox, Go to **Tools** menu and type 'cache' in **search box**, you will view options regarding Cache. Now set the '**Limit cache to**' 0 MB.

Answer (score 0):

i have a problem like this too. I have searched on google and i find a solutions then  solved. I will tell you how can you solved step by step on Eclipse IDE.

- 1 Open ECLIPSE IDE
- 2 Window -> Show View -> Click Servers
- 3 Double Click your server. (Tomcat, WildFly etc.)
- 4 Click **publishing** on the right side of the screen
- 5 You will see three radio button. Click **Automatically publish after a build**. That's it.
- But if you are using **Wildfly**  after

  - Open **Application Reload Behavior**. (Below **Publishing**)
  - Disable **Use default patter**
  - Change `\.jar$` to `\.jar$|\.class$`
  - Save project (Ctrl + S )
  - Restart IDE.

Your changes will  appear on the screen now. I hope it has helped.

Comment: Original solutions is here. http://kod5.org/eclipsewildfly-asda-servlet-icin-hot-deploy/

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Eclipse was closing the project by right clicking on the name of the project on the project explorer then opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

As **cs94njw** answered, but if Tomcat **10** then:

There is a "development" setting that should be set to "true" to allow Tomcat to check for changes to JSP files.  And set the "modificationTestInterval" parameter to "0" so that the page is updated immediately after saving.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>development</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>modificationTestInterval</param-name>
  <param-value>0</param-value>
</init-param>
```

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration

Also, server settings are copied to eclipse separately and they could be changed relative to the original settings (there are two "web.xm" files)

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting all the contents in the jsp and then refresh.
Then copy your updated code back once empty jsp shows.

Comment: Try deleting the jsp altogether.