# Load dynamic html file in jsp

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets

Here is the flow:
input.jsp --> User clicks Submit button --> An html file is created dynamically based on the form input fields and saved to the file system, for eg,         folder/TestProject/view.html --> output.jsp should retrieve the view.html and display its contents.

In my output.jsp, this is how I am retrieving the html file

```
<jsp:include page="/folder/TestProject/view.html"/>
```

This works fine the first time. When the form fields are updated again and the user clicks Submit the next time on, the view.html generates fine with the updated contents from the form fields, but my output.jsp still loads the view.html with previous contents (i.e. the view.html created the first time). How do I tell the jsp to load the updated html? Is there any caching going on in the browser or am I missing anything? Or is there any other alternative to retrieve dynamic html in jsp? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please mention which IDE you are using for the development.It is easy to answer if you post the screenshot of the folder structure if you are using an IDE. Also remember to add the code snippets of your source files like **input.jsp**,**output.jsp** etc ..

Comment: I am using eclipse. All I am doing in output.jsp is trying to load the html that changes dynamically using the jsp include. So my output,jsp contains the jsp include tag. input.jsp contains a form with 3 input fields and a submit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP page is not getting refreshed after updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036236/jsp-page-is-not-getting-refreshed-after-updating)

Comment: @user3376592 Is your **input.jsp** and **output.jsp** is in the same **WEB-INF** folder. Please check both are in  **WEB-INF** folder. If isn't put them both in **WEB-INF** and check

Comment: Yes, both are in the same folder. Also, I included the following tags in my output.jsp
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>

Comment: Have you include this type of code snippet in your **input.jsp**  `<form action="output.jsp" method="post">` ?.

Comment: Yes, my input jsp has an action

Comment: @user3376592 And you must include in the **output.jsp**  `<%= request.getParameterValues("firstName") %>` if the **input.jsp** hast a input field like `<input type="text" name="firstName" value=""/>`. That is simple.This will work.

Comment: It is not that simple. I am doing something different. Please read my original question. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Why do you create a html file?

Comment: How are you passing the values to the output.jsp ? Do the output.jsp have an action?