# How Do I Cache A JSP Page Between DB Updates

Tags: java, spring, jsp, caching

I am writing a Java Spring web application that only updates the database every 15 minutes and was looking for ways to update the page only after every 15 minutes accordingly and serve the latest version of the page as response multiple times in between database updates.

In order words, I want the page to be dynamic 
& updated every 15 minutes when the DB changes but served as though it were a static page always.
How can I successfully prepare and cache a JSP page into a server side (x)html this manner?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with JSP to give an educated answer, but I found [this question where it appears that someone was having exactly the opposite issue, they wanted to get rid of caching.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036236/jsp-page-is-not-getting-refreshed-after-updating). That question has some details on how to control caching, and maybe the answers will give you a clue as to what to look for in order to find what you need to make it cache every 15 minutes. Sorry I can't be of more help though.

Answer (score 0):

The way to update JSP dynamically while not refreshing the page is to use AJAX.

You can basically use JavaScript to get the data and update the DOM(e.g. HTML element values) every 15 minutes.

Comment: I am trying to do it on the server side, then serve the prepared or translated jsp ( to html or xhtml  ) page in the server side as well as multiple response in between DB update or server side page change. Get it ?